# Subversion Creates HTTP Links Automatically

Tags: http, svn, hyperlink, tortoisesvn, commit

I want to do that:
When I use a tortoise svn and create a folder then commit it; Server creates a link for the folder automatically.

This is a system which I dont know how it works.

1. I Create a folder = "document"
2. Commit it to a server. Some pc in the local office.
3. Then when I write a "http://server/Folders/Doc/"; I see the entire folder.

Do you know how can I build a system like that?

Comment: How is the repo currently being served? via apache?

Comment: Then it should currently work. Say you have the repo `Folders` which is mapped to `http://server/Folders`. You add `Doc` to the repo and commit it, you should then be able to navigate to `http://server/Folders/Doc`. Are you saying that you can't?